# Perl file handler for writing and reading

Tags: perl, file

I am trying to write the output of a cmd to a file and grep for a pattern in the output and push it into array,if found. I am facing issue in writing the output to a file

The below Code without usage of file handler,arrays works fine and prints output

```
my $output = `cmd to get output`;
print "output is : $output\n";
```

But if I place the same code inside a file handler , then its not even printing the hardcoded word `output is :`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

 foreach my $cfg_file (@cfg_files){
 #open the file handler for both read and write mode
  open my $fh1, '+>', 'c:\TEMP\cfg.txt' or die $!;
   while ( <$fh1> ) { 
    my $output = `cmd to get output using $cfg_file`;
    print "output is : $output\n";
    print $fh1 $output;   #write the output into file

    if (/$pattern/) {   #read the file for a specific pattern
           print "$_";
         push(@matching_lines, $_);        
    }
  }
}
 print Dumper(\@matching_lines);
```

The code is not even throwing warnings .The output I am getting is just
`$VAR1 = [];`

Comment: What's the deal with the loop over `@cfg_files` that you don't actually use? Are those the files you want to read from?

Comment: It's called a *file handle*, not a *file handler*. It allows you to hold onto something, not handle something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while (<$fh1>)` attempts to read from the `$fh1` filehandle. It there was nothing in the file at all, the loop body is never executed. Incidentally, the `+>` clobbers the file first, so the file is indeed empty as the code gets to `while`.

You can drop the `while` loop and test the `$pattern` against the variable `$output` you just got.

```
open my $fh1, '+>', 'c:\TEMP\cfg.txt' or die $!;

my $output = `cmd to get output`;
print "output is : $output\n";
print $fh1 $output;   #write the output into file

if ($output =~ /($pattern)/s) {  # test and capture from output
     print "$1\n";
     push (@matching_lines, $1);        
}
```

Since the output may have multiple lines we add `/s` to the regex.

The rest of your code would be the same.

Comment: perfect. While loops was the mistake I made.

Comment: I am using $cfg_file in the `cmd to get output`. But now after removing while loop, I am getting error `use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)`  Do  I need to reopen the while loop after writing and before reading ?

Comment: I didnt see the change in if loop you suggested. Now I am not getting the error

Comment: now `print $output` has the whole ouptut from the `cmd to get output` and not just the lines matching pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109084/discussion-between-jill448-and-zdim).